# Ajax - page is reloaded when user press enter to submit data

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a simple form to send message from one person to another, and the message is sent by AJAX with method POST, without reload the page. I have an , and the problem is when the user press [ENTER] in this field, the AJAX don't work and the page is reloaded. I qant a form, that when the user press ENTER, the ajax runs normally.

See my document:
-Javascript:

```
function enviarMensagem()
    {
        var remetente = document.getElementById('remetente').value;
        var destinatario = document.getElementById('destinatario').value;
        var mensagem = document.getElementById("mensagem").value;
        if(mensagem.length == 0 || mensagem.length  > 128)
        {
            return;
        }
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("mensagens").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "saida.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("remetente=" + remetente + "&destinatario=" + destinatario + "&mensagem=" + mensagem);
    }
```

-HTML:

```
<form action="" >
    <input type="hidden" id="remetente" name="remetente" value="Erick">
    <input type="hidden" id="destinatario" name="destinatario" value="Fernanda">
    <input type="text" id="mensagem" /> <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="enviarMensagem();">
</form>
<div id="mensagens"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only applying the Ajax function to the onclick handler of the button. You need to add it to the onsubmit action of the form.

```
<form action=""  onsubmit="enviarMensagem(); return false;">
<input type="hidden" id="remetente" name="remetente" value="Erick">
<input type="hidden" id="destinatario" name="destinatario" value="Fernanda">
<input type="text" id="mensagem" /> <input type="button" value="Enviar" >
```

The submission on the form can be initiated from the click of the submit button, or the keyup event with the Enter key. Adding the listener to the onsubmit action covers both.